# OSSEC is not running

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, ossec

I have an two ec2 instances. In one I have installed ossec server and in other I have installed ossec agent.

Here are my server config `INBOUND` (security group/firewall) :

```
port:514   source:0.0.0.0/0
port:1514   source:0.0.0.0/0
```

But it seems to be not working. In my agent log file I keep on getting:

```
2012/08/28 06:52:52 ossec-agentd: INFO: Using IPv4 for: x.x.x.x.x.x .
2012/08/28 06:53:13 ossec-agentd(4101): WARN: Waiting for server reply (not started). Tried: 'x.x.x.x.x'.
```

#### Edit:

Running `sudo netstat --inet -nlp | grep ossec`. I'm getting:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1514            0.0.0.0:*                           26027/ossec-remoted
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: On the server, give us the output of `netstat --inet -nlp | grep ossec`?

Comment: @quanta: I have edited my question..

Comment: What does `ossec.log` on the server say? Are you sure the client's IP is correct in `agent_control -l` list?

Comment: It says `ossec-remoted(1403): ERROR: Incorrectly formated message from 'my client ip'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says ossec-remoted(1403): ERROR: Incorrectly formated message from
>   'my client ip'.

It means that you have imported the wrong authentication keys (maybe from a different agent) or the IP address you configured the agent is different from what the server is seeing. Removing and re-adding the key (make sure the IP is correct) and try again.

Comment: Now on the server logs I can see mess like `ossec-logcollector: INFO: Started (pid: 30441)`. But still in client I'm getting the same `WARN: Waiting for server reply (not started). Tried: 'x.x.x.x.x'.` Error!

Comment: What could be the issue?

Comment: Am I need to open any ports in client side??

Comment: No. Which firewall are you using? Make sure that you have opened those up for UDP and allowed outbound traffic.

Comment: Can you be clear? Outbound traffic in server side or client side? What port I need to open? I'm very new to OSSEC, kindly help me.

Comment: Server side. Please tell us which firewall are you running? Where did you put the above rules `port:1514   source:0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: I set those firewall rules in amazon vpc security groups. So what outbounds I need to open at server side?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon EC2 and Security Groups. Try this: http://www.mail-archive.com/ossec-list@googlegroups.com/msg14965.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was caused by an unsynced queue between server and agent, after server migration.

Queues "/var/ossec/queue/rids" must be copied from an old server.
Also, see [Wazuh's recommendations for migrating from OSSEC](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/migrating-from-ossec/ossec-agent.html).

You can clear Directory "./rid" on windows agent as workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem few months ago with ossec-hids v2.9.2. on CentOS 7

If you have imported the correct authentication keys you need to enable IPv6 on ossec server in order to be able to run `ossec-remoted`. Remember to restart the `ossec-hids` service after make the changes on IPv6 configuration.

I don't know if is a feature or a bug, but after enabling IPv6 `ossec-remoted` answered the ossec-clients.

Answer (score 0):

Simply goto on effected client "my-client-ip" and remove client ID which will be found inside directory"/var/ossec/queue/rids/" and then restart ossec-hids service and agent will active on the console.